# How to merge multiple jdbc inputs in logstash configuration based on condition of single column?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

I have two tables in sql server i.e. AppDetails and AppBranchDetails.
I want to read all rows of these two tables and merge based on the condition.

Below are the two queries which I want to run:

1. select id as colg_id, name, sirname from AppDetails order by id
2. select id as branch_id, branch_name, branch_add from AppBranchDetails order by id

From the above two queries, "id" is a primary key which is same for both the tables.

The output will looks like below for **id == 1**:

```
{
  "name": "ram",
  "sirname": "patil",
  "id": 1,
  "BRANCH": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "branch_name": "EE",
      "branch_add": "IND"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "branch_name": "ME",
      "branch_add": "IND"
    }
  ]
}
```

The output will looks like below for **id == 2**:

```
{
  "name": "sham",
  "sirname": "bhosle",
  "id": 2,
  "BRANCH": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "branch_name": "SE",
      "branch_add": "US"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "branch_name": "FE",
      "branch_add": "US"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying with below configuration (app.conf):

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433;databaseName=AAA;"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_user => "sa"
    jdbc_password => "sa@111"
    statement => "select id as colg_id, name, sirname from AppDetails order by id"
    tracking_column => "colg_id"
    use_column_value => true
    type => "college"
  }
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433;databaseName=AAA;"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_user => "sa"
    jdbc_password => "sa@111"
    statement => "select id as branch_id, branch_name, branch_add from AppBranchDetails order by id"
    tracking_column => "branch_id"
    use_column_value => true
    type => "branch"
  }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "branch" {
        aggregate {
        task_id => "%{branch_id}"
        code => "
            map['BRANCH'] ||= []
            map['BRANCH'] << event.get('branch_id')
            map['BRANCH'] << event.get('branch_name')
            map['BRANCH'] << event.get('branch_add')
            event.cancel()
        "
        push_previous_map_as_event => true
        timeout => 5
        }
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "@version" , "@timestamp" ]
        }
    }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest how I can make the result which I have mentioned above.

Comment: Since both request seems to be done on the same DB, wouldn't it be easier to do the merge in DB with a `JOIN`?

Comment: @baudsp- I tried that way also but seems like there is two or more results from "AppBranchDetails" table for single id